# Vi/Vim Dictionary Get Whole Line

Tags: dictionary, autocomplete, vi

I have a dictionary file used to autocomplete in VI. I know that I need use "CTRL+ X, CTRL+K" for search and autocomplete word or line.
Example file dic.:

> xi_x1_a1
>
> xi_x1_a2
>
> xi_x1_a3
>
> **xi_x1_a4**
>
> **xi_x2_a4**
>
> xi_x1_a6
>
> xi_x1_b
>
> ...

In Vi/Vim if I enter: xi "CTRL+X, CTRL+k", then I will receive all line in the dictionary at the cursor. It is not useful because my dictionary file has many lines.

How can I only enter "a4, CTRL+x, CTRL+k"? Then I only get  two match lines in the cursor for autocomplete line.

> **xi_x1_a4**
>
> **xi_x2_a4**

Thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `completefunc`. That allows you to specify the way you want to complete.

If you edit your `~/.vimrc` and put something like:

```
function! MyCompleteFunc(findstart, base)
  if (a:findstart == 1)
    normal b
    return col(".") - 1
  else
    " Hardcoded path to dictionary. You could tweak this to use
    " whatever dictionary you have set with `set dictionary=`
    let l:data = readfile("/home/david/mydic.txt")
    return filter(l:data, 'v:val =~ ".*' . a:base . '.*"')
  endif
endfunction

set completefunc=MyCompleteFunc
```

it should make the trick.

Then you'll be able to use
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

See `:help i_^x`, `:help 'completefunc'` and `:help complete-function` for more info.